# How to get user input for tkinter Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating an app that tracks progress of tasks with progress bars. The idea is that I ask the user to input details about the task they have to complete( Client Name and Client Contact). Whenever you click the button to add a task, I should get the following.

The client name

The client contact

Progress bar

Increment button

However every time I run the code below I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/algor/OneDrive/Documents/Computer Science/Testgrid.py", line 44, in <module>
    new = CNuser.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

I tried looking at examples of dealing with user input in tkinter but had no success.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import smtplib
import os

tasks = Tk()
tasks.geometry("1920x1080")


# These are the contents of the tasks tab


rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    tasks.rowconfigure(rows, weight=20)
    tasks.columnconfigure(rows, weight=20)
    rows += 1

count = 1
count1 = 0
subtitle = Label(tasks, text="Task List:").grid(row=0, column=0)


CN = Label(tasks, text="Client Name*").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
CNuser = Entry(tasks, textvariable=CN).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)

CC = Label(tasks, text="Client Contact*").grid(row=5, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
CCuser = Entry(tasks, textvariable=CC).grid(row=6, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)

# progress bars


def addtask():
    global count
    global count1
    global CNuser
    global CCuser

    new = CNuser.get()


    def step():
        my_progress["value"] += 20

    Label(tasks, text=new, font=("Calibri")).grid(
        column=1, row=count + 1)
    Label(tasks, text=CCuser, font=("Calibri")).grid(
        column=1, row=count + 2)
    my_progress = ttk.Progressbar(
        tasks, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=600, mode='determinate')
    my_progress.grid(column=1, row=count + 3)

    my_button = Button(tasks, text="New action complete",
                       command=step).grid(column=1, row=count + 4)

    for i in range(1, 6):
        count1 += 1
    count = count + count1


Button(tasks, text="New task", command=addtask).grid(row=1, column=0)


tasks.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put full error message (startingt word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screensht). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common mistake

```
variable = Widget().grid()
```

This assing `None` to `variable` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` returns `None`

You have to do it in two steps

```
variable = Widget()
variable.grid()
```